# Creating a name column from email

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that has an email column in the following format:

```
Email
Jane_Anderson@email.com
Andy_Smith@email.com
```

I'd like to create a new column that tells me the full name of the person, based off of the email column (removing the _ and @email.com). So the new column would look like:

```
Full Name
Jane Anderson
Andy Smith
```

Comment: from discussion below - real world data rarely is this well behaved. Might you run into 1) more than one first name, or 2) using dot instead of underscore to separate names?

Comment: @Sirius In real world data, there may be multiple first name and last name.  But, I would say that people who post questions here may not be working on real world data.  It could be a clean dataset or even some practise test for learning.  So, if we look every question by that generalizable POV, it would become a complex solution needlessly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `extract` to capture the first word (`(\\w+)`) followed by underscore, then one or more letters in a second capture group followed by the @ and other characters

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df1, Email, into = c("Full", "Name"), "^(\\w+)_([A-Za-z]+)@.*")
#  Full     Name
#1 Jane Anderson
#2 Andy    Smith
```

---

Or use `base R` with `read.table` after removing the suffix part

```
read.table(text = trimws(df1$Email, whitespace = "@.*"), sep="_",
      header = FALSE, col.names = c("Full", "Name"))
#   Full     Name
#1 Jane Anderson
#2 Andy    Smith
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Email = c("Jane_Anderson@email.com", 
"Andy_Smith@email.com"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: might want to rewrite it to handle multiple first names, its not unreasonable

Comment: @Sirius without a pattern of how that multiple names are occuring, it is not easy to suggest

Comment: Honestly, this is probably doomed to fail with real-world data. Real people don’t neatly fall into “Firstname Lastname”.

Comment: That is true, but I assume the OP have only this pattern in their data (`I have a dataframe that has an email column in the following format:`) or else the OP should specify that.

Comment: doing what OP does, but allowing for underscores and dots to split names would go along way, just shove all n-1 first words into the first name , and the single nth word as the last name. His use of `format` could easily just relate to column names. Anyway.

Comment: @Sirius Can you please comment your concerns below the OP's post as I read the post as `I have a dataframe that has an email column in the following format:`